# Are there any prototype-based languages with a whole development cycle?

Tags: javascript, ruby, programming-languages, prototype

**Are there any real-world prototype-based programming languages with a whole development cycle?**

"A whole development cycle" like Ruby and Python: web frameworks, scripting/interacting with the system, tools for debugging, profiling, etc.

Thank you

***A brief note on PBPLs: (let's call these languages PBPL : prototype-based programming language)***

There are some PBPLs out there. Some are being widely used like JavaScript (which Node.js may bring it into the field - or may not!). One other language is ActionScript which is also a PBPL but tightly bound to Flash VM (is it correct to say so?).

From less known ones I can speak of Lua which has a strong reputation in game development (mostly spread by WOW) but never took off as a full language. Lua has a table concept which can provide you some sort of prototype based programming facility.

There is also JScript (Windows scripting tool) which is already pointless by the newcomer PowerShell (I have used JScript to manipulate IIS but I never understood what is JScript!).

Others can be named like io (indeed very very neat, you will fall in love with it; absolutely impossible to use) and REBOL (What is this all about? A proprietary scripting tool? You must be kidding!) and newLISP (Which is actually a full language, but no one ever heard about it).

For sure there are much more to list here but either I do not remember or I did not understood them as a real world thing, like Self).

Comment: ActionScript isn't prototype based anymore. The first version was, the second was, but only behind the scenes, but the third isn't in any practical sense.

Comment: Thanks Theo; I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not found one and the only candidate (JavaScript) is still spending very first steps (like Node.js).

Still one other valid candidate would be JavaScript! There is a .NET based implementation named [IronJS](https://github.com/fholm/IronJS) which is implemented in F# and is going pretty well. This way one can have whole .NET development cycle at his toolbox. It is based on DLR and can be used in both .NET and Mono!

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that JavaScript is a real world language. The main difference is that it tends to be embedded into lots of different environments rather than being a stand alone development environment.

Aside from the obvious use in a browser, JavaScript can be used on the server side using [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) (which is becoming very popular as a database both for websites and [the desktop](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/desktopcouch)) or [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) - there are [lots of others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Server-side_JavaScript_solutions) as well. It can also be used to create desktop applications via [seed](http://live.gnome.org/Seed) or [gjs](http://live.gnome.org/Gjs).

As for debugging tools, these are included in most web browsers and there are extensions such as firebug.

The approach *is* different in JavaScript - instead of having a core language and using libraries to access different programming environments, it is embedded directly into these environments.

Comment: An explanation as to why this was downvoted would be helpful.

Comment: I didn't down vote but I could see why someone would. It doesn't really answer the question and is more of a response to the previous answer. I agree with what you're saying, especially since js is the most widely used programming language. Unfortunately I will also not up vote because this is more of a comment directed at the first response.

Comment: This is not a response to the other answer - in fact this was posted a few minutes before the other answer. It was intended to answer the question. JavaScript is a PBPL and has a 'full development cycle', at least in my interpretation of the words, but this 'development cycle' is implemented by having lots of embedded interpreters instead of lots of libraries and one main interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like it. Checking out the Wikipedia list, I can't say any of them are particularly popular for systems-type or standalone programming. And I have a few theories why:

- Inertia - people are more familiar with procedural/procedure-class based languages. In the same way procedural languages are more popular than functional, I think we find it easier to mentally keep track of the objects we've specified beforehand
- Less error-prone - When I use a class, I can't use things not specified in that class. It's a bit less flexible, but when working on a large project I'm very, very grateful to be able to look at the spec for an object (even if I've written that object) and know how the object will behave. That is, I know the compiler will probably throw an error if I try to do something stupid like use the wrong variable name.
- You mention "scripting/interacting with the system". As far as that goes, classes aren't even particularly popular. One-off scripts may use a few functions, or even just straight procedural code. I know if I write a simple little Python script, I'll have a few simple functions and I'll use builtin objects. It's OO, but I'm not writing anything.
- No/not many suitable languages. This is I think the biggest one. Lua's great for embedded scripting, but I don't think it can replace Python/Perl scripts in my toolkit.
- Prejudice - the sordid past of Javascript has *not* been good for prototype-based languages, I don't think. Javascript's actually a pretty nice language, once you see code written by somebody that understands it, but there's still a lot of derision - it's seen like a kiddie language. If you say "I'm a Javascript programmer", it's hard to be taken seriously.
- **EDIT** It's either a sign or a symptom, but most PT languages are embedded or application-specific scripting languages (Lua in games or for UIs, Javascript in webpages or for the UI like in Firefox, etc). I'm not sure why this is, but they are either more suited to application customizing or otherwise-embeddedness, or that's what the common implementations are designed for. Python can be easily embedded into a program, and it sometimes is, but it's more common standalone.

This may be more philosophical than you're looking for, and I'm by no means a prototype-based expert, but I've done a fair bit of Javascript and fiddled with Lua. I stand by my answer, though, based on at least personal experience. YMMV.

I see no reason why a PT language as useful as Python couldn't be written, but it doesn't seem like anyone's done it.

Comment: (on your edited paragraph) Exactly! That proves this approach provides a robust foundation for behavioral reuse: in this case manipulating application functionality and flexible mechanism for data bending (yes: data bending)!